# Capacitor - Set origin for cors

Tags: android, capacitor

Is it possible to set a default origin of `https://example.org` as opposed to the standard `http://localhost` on an Android Capacitor app?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The origin is handled by the webview and depends on the url where the app is served, so you can’t change the origin directly, but you can change the url capacitor uses, which will change the origin. To change the url, configure hostname and androidSchene properties of server object in capacitor.config.json

```
"server": {
    "hostname": "example.org",
    "androidScheme": "https"
}
```

https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/basics/configuring-your-app#common-configuration

Comment: Is it possible to change the scheme for android to be the same as ios "capacitor"?  So they both come from capacitor://localhost

Comment: Yeah, it’s possible to change it, but the origin will be just capacitor://, so won’t be the same. It was reported to google and they said that they won’t fix it nor recommend to use a custom scheme on android.

Comment: I was stuck for the last couple of days with CORS problems on Capacitor/Android where all my network calls were failing, although the iOS version was working perfectly fine. This actually solved my issue by setting the correct origin (hostname). Thanks a lot.